# Delphi application with login / logout - how to implement?

Tags: delphi

Application has a Login form and a Main form.

Applications DPR file has code to load Login form first, and when Login form returns successful login, then Main form is created and loaded.

When user logs out via a menu command in Main form, it should close the Main form and load the Login form.

Application exits only when user selects Exit in the Main form (or when user Cancels out of the Login form).

Using code in the application's DPR file, is it possible to code this?

Here is the code that presently exists:

```
program H;

uses
  Forms,
  SysUtils,
  Registry,
  MidasLib,
  Dialogs,
  Controls,
  uDatamod in 'uDatamod.pas' {datamod: TDataModule} ,
  uMain in 'uMain.pas' {fMain} ,
  uMtlUpd in 'uMtlUpd.pas' {fMtlUpd} ,
  uReportPrv in 'uReportPrv.pas' {fReportPrv} ,
  uCamera in 'uCamera.pas' {fCamera} ,
  uConfig in 'uConfig.pas' {fConfig} ,
  uFuncs in 'uFuncs.pas',
  uLogin in 'uLogin.pas' {fLogin} ,
  uAdmin in 'uAdmin.pas' {fAdmin};

// MidasLib is required.

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.Title := 'HTech';

  if ((ParamCount = 1) and (UpperCase(ParamStr(1)) = '/CONFIG')) or
    (getHServerHostName = EmptyStr) then
  begin
    Application.CreateForm(TfConfig, fConfig);

    Application.Run;
  end
  else
  begin
    if not testHServerConnection then
    begin
      ShowMessage('Error: Could not connect to HServer');

      Exit;
    end;

    Application.CreateForm(Tdatamod, Datamod);

    while not TerminateApplicationFlag do
    begin

      fLogin := TfLogin.Create(Application);
      try
        if fLogin.ShowModal = mrOk then
        begin
          LoggedInEmployeeID := fLogin.FEmployeeID;
          LoggedInEmployeeNm := fLogin.edtFirstName.Text + ' ' +
            fLogin.edtLastName.Text;
          AdminLogin := fLogin.FAdminUser;
          FinanceLogin := fLogin.FFinanceUser;
        end
        else
        begin

          FreeAndNil(fLogin);
          FreeAndNil(Datamod);
          Exit;
        end;
      finally
        // FreeAndNil(fLogin);
      end;

      if AdminLogin then
        Application.CreateForm(TfAdmin, fAdmin)
      else
      begin
        FreeAndNil(fLogin);
        if not Assigned(fMain) then
          Application.CreateForm(TfMain, fMain);
        fMain.FHServerHost := getHServerHostName;
      end;

      Application.Run;

    end;
  end;

end.
```

The problem with the above code is that after one iteration (after user performs Logout in Main form), the application exits (control is returned to the operating system) because " fLogin.ShowModal " exits without showing the Login form.

Here is the code from the Main form:

```
Procedure LogoutProcedure;
  begin
    TerminateApplicationFlag := False;
    Close;
  end;

Procedure ExitProcedure;
  begin
    TerminateApplicationFlag := True;
    Close;
  end;
```

I'm stuck with this and would appreciate any advice or corrections in getting it to work.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Steve Faleiro

Comment: Show the login form from the .dpr. Create it by calling `TLoginForm.Create`. Do *not* use `Application.CreateForm`. Show it with `ShowModal`. When it returns decide whether or not to proceed. If you proceed create your main form and this time use `Application.CreateForm`. Then call Application.Run. Sorry this is all in a comment but an overzealous admin has close the question even though I can understand what you ask.

Comment: Of course it's possible to code that. Start typing!

Comment: @David Heffernan: +1 for "overzealous admin", I understood question too

Comment: Great to see the SO community working well to reopen this question and provide help. Good work people!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this very simple solution is sufficient:

The project file:

```
program Project1;

uses
  Forms,
  FMain in 'FMain.pas' {MainForm},
  FLogin in 'FLogin.pas' {LoginForm};

{$R *.res}

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
  Login;
  Application.Run;
end.
```

The main form:

```
unit FMain;

interface

uses
  Classes, Controls, Forms, StdCtrls, FLogin;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    LogoutButton: TButton;
    procedure LogoutButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMainForm.LogoutButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Login;
end;

end.
```

And the login form:

```
unit FLogin;

interface

uses
  Classes, Controls, Forms, StdCtrls;

type
  TLoginForm = class(TForm)
    LoginButton: TButton;
    CancelButton: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

procedure Login;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure Login;
begin
  with TLoginForm.Create(nil) do
  try
    Application.MainForm.Hide;
    if ShowModal = mrOK then
      Application.MainForm.Show
    else
      Application.Terminate;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TLoginForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LoginButton.ModalResult := mrOK;
  CancelButton.ModalResult := mrCancel;
end;

end.
```

Now, this answer works here, quite well with Delphi 7, but I suspect problems with more recent versions were `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar` and `Application.ShowMainForm` are `True` by default. When so, try to set them to `False`.

Comment: How can you add a closequery to this example without causing the screen to flicker when Login form tries to close ?

Comment: You mean that for a split second the MainForm is visible after canceling the login? Then add `Application.Minimize` before `Application.Terminate` (both wrapped in a `begin`-`end` block) in the `Login` routine.

Comment: doing that causes the application on successful login to close without even opening the mainform.

Comment: @user763539 You wrapped `Application.Minimize` and `Application.Terminate` between a `begin` and `end`? Then this should not happen!

Comment: you mean : else  begin
    Application.Minimize;
    Application.Terminate;
    end;
     finally
    Free;
  end; ??? You still get a screen jerk ...

Comment: @NGLN mind answering on how to prevent the screen jerk ?

Comment: @user763539 I am still not sure what you are asking since I cannot reproduce your problem. Maybe it is better to ask as a new question. Also to attract more people possibly willing to help. Then you can comprehensively explain what is the matter, better then here within these short comments.

Comment: @NGLN In your example the main form is shown after a successful login (modal result OK of the button). However if I close the loginform without entering any login parameters then the application, for a split second tries to open the main  form before it dies so it kind of looks like a screen jerk (because the main form is actually shown for a split of a second) . I am trying to avoid this attempt of a main form  show.  Understand ?

Comment: @user763539 Yes, I kind of understand, but I cannot reproduce. Not in D7 and not in XE2. I did reproduce this "jerk" _before_ the login form is shown, by setting `MainForm.Visible=True` in the IDE, but that doesn't sound like the glitch you are describing. For the record: have you set it `True` too? Then try setting it back to `False`. Otherwise, please ask this as a new question by referring to this question, because I suspect we won't get to an satisfactory solution here within these comments.