# delphi Login Form

Tags: forms, delphi, authentication

in my Delphi program i've a Login Form and it's Displayed Before the Main Form is Created , but the issue that i'm facing is that i want to Login Check to be processed in the main form , that means the Login Form will use the Main Form to check and proceed ,

please read the comment placed in :

> procedure LogInButtonClick(Sender: TObject) ;

here is the TLoginForm code ( [from delphi.about.com](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/password_login.htm) ):

```
    unit login;

 interface

 uses
   Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes,
   Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls;

 type
   TLoginForm = class(TForm)
     LogInButton: TButton;
     pwdLabel: TLabel;
     passwordEdit: TEdit;
     procedure LogInButtonClick(Sender: TObject) ;
   public
     class function Execute : boolean;
   end;

 implementation
 {$R *.dfm}

 class function TLoginForm.Execute: boolean;
 begin
   with TLoginForm.Create(nil) do
   try
     Result := ShowModal = mrOk;
   finally
     Free;
   end;
 end;

 procedure TLoginForm.LogInButtonClick(Sender: TObject) ;
 begin
   if passwordEdit.Text = 'delphi' then
   {
   Here how it's possible to use :
    if MainForm.text=passwordEdit.Text then 
    ModalResult := mrOK
    }

     ModalResult := mrOK
   else
     ModalResult := mrAbort;
 end;

 end.
```

and here's the Main Program Initialization flow :

```
program PasswordApp;

 uses
   Forms,
   main in 'main.pas' {MainForm},
   login in 'login.pas' {LoginForm};

 {$R *.res}

 begin
   if TLoginForm.Execute then
   begin
     Application.Initialize;
     Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm) ;
     Application.Run;
   end
   else
   begin
     Application.MessageBox('You are not authorized to use the application. The password is "delphi".', 'Password Protected Delphi application') ;
   end;
 end.
```

thank you

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You want to access the `MainForm` from the `LoginForm`, but your project code shows that you're not creating the `MainForm` until after `LoginForm` has displayed successfully. You can't have it both ways. If you don't create `MainForm` before `LoginForm` tries to access it, you can't access things on `MainForm`.

Comment: yes , because i really need it to use the main form to Check then proceed

Comment: You can use a DataModule to _check_ whatever you want, and share that DataModule between your login form and main form.

Comment: The intention of visual controls (Form, Edit, etc.) is **Interaction** and **not** storing data. Once you realize this, you'll never face this question again ;o)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delphi application with login / logout - how to implement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839648/delphi-application-with-login-logout-how-to-implement)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you need the main form to be created first, then create it first:

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);//created, but not shown
  if TLoginForm.Execute then//now the login form can refer to the main form
    Application.Run//this shows the main form
  else
    Application.MessageBox('....');
end;
```

---

That's a direct and naive answer to the question that you asked. Thinking more broadly, I would encourage you to move the login testing out of the main form. Put it somewhere  that can be used by whatever higher-level code needs to. The design you are currently working towards has unhealthy coupling.

Comment: No it will not. The main form will only be shown if the login is successful. Read the comments in the code.

Comment: @user1998327: the MainForm is not shown until `Application.Run` is called. But if needed, you could just set `Application.ShowMainForm` to False and then call `MainForm.Show` manually if the login is successful.

Comment: So that mean , i can use "
    if MainForm.text=passwordEdit.Text then 
    ModalResult := mrOK "

Comment: @David Heffernan many thanks i will test it and give you a sign

Answer (score 5):

I usually do this from the `OnCreate` of the `MainForm`; Or from the `OnCreate` of the `DataModule`, if you have one. For example:

```
TMainForm.OnCreate(Sender: TObject);
var F: TLoginForm;
begin
  F := TLoginForm.Create(Self);
  try
    F.ShowModal;
  finally F.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I don't like messing with the `DPR` file too much. This works, shows the forms in the correct order, and if the `TMainForm` was auto-created by Delphi then the `MainForm` variable is already assigned and ready to use when the `OnCreate` fires;

PS: Accesing the `MainForm` variable is actually bad design, but it's there if you want it.

Comment: How do you stop the call to `Application.Run`?

Comment: I'm usually very blunt about it: `TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess, 1)` - that works nicely :)

Comment: That would be fine. `Halt` would be more Pascalish.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447491/757830), but with slightly different behaviour, I previously answered [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7845993/757830) which is capable of reuse in application's lifetime.