# Obtain data from available form to autocreated one

Tags: delphi

I would like to transfer data from the statusbar of Form2 (which is on the list of available forms and used for login purposes), to the statusbar on the MainForm (which is autocreated one). 
If I use :

```
procedure TMainForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := Form2.AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text;
end;
```

I get an access violation error. . Why is this happening? How can I get over this?

Comment: 1- You're accessing invalid memory, probably form2 is not created yet. 2- By starting using the debugger.

Comment: Debugger does not help me much. But since I am loging in from that form that means it is created. But it seems all data on it is lost as soon as I display my main form.

Comment: Can you can provide an SSCCE then?

Comment: It's almost a certainty that your form doesn't exist. If you are logging on with it then it has probably been freed. For example, `Action := caFree;` will do that. I find it useful to delete the auto created variable `FormX: TFormX;` that is found just above `implementation`. That way you can control the variable yourself.

Comment: I was actually following this accepted answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839648/delphi-application-with-login-logout-how-to-implement

Comment: @user3719777: Actually, no. You weren't. And the debugger would clearly show what the issue is if you step through the code. Start with the constructor of `Form2`.

Comment: The debugger will help if you use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment I would say that the following is occurring:

The code you would be using for your login form is this:

```
procedure Login;
begin
  with TForm2.Create(nil) do
  try
    Application.MainForm.Hide;
    if ShowModal = mrOK then
      Application.MainForm.Show
    else
      Application.Terminate;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

What is happening here is that there is an implicit variable for TLoginForm. This is not the same as the auto created variable which would be `Form2: TForm2;` which sits in the TForm2 unit. This variable is freed directly after the form closes.

To see what I mean. If you delete the variable called Form2 from your application, the only part of the code that won't compile is your line in your original post.

What you would have to do if you wanted to do this sort of thing is something like this (I have changed the name of TLoginForm to your Form2).

```
procedure Login;
begin
  Form2 := TForm2.Create(nil);
  Application.MainForm.Hide;
  if Form2.ShowModal = mrOK then
    Application.MainForm.Show
  else
  begin
    Form2.Free;
    Application.Terminate;
  end;
end;
```

The you would have to free your Form2 when you close your main form. I would really not recommend doing this sort of thing though. As a quick fix, you would be far better off saving the text `AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text` in a global variable in the OnClose event of the Form2 with something like this:

```
procedure TForm2.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  g_MySavedVariable := AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text;
end;
```

And then loading it in the main form with:

```
procedure TMainForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := g_MySavedVariable;
end;
```

Even this is not ideal but should get you up and running.

If you are looking for some code for a login form where you pass data between the login form and the main form then you are probably better off looking at this question in StackOverflow ([delphi Login Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447331/delphi-login-form)) along with the answers by David and Cosmin. My personal preference is for the solution by Cosmin as you don't need to mess with the DPR and there is no global variables involved.