# Delphi : Want to run some code when a form is displayed for the first time

Tags: delphi

Using Delphi RAD Studio 10.2 and Object Pascal.

The first form I display is a login form. Then following a successful login, depending on the type of user (based on the UserID), another form is displayed. I would like to populate this second form's fields with some data as the form is shown. So far I have not been able to find a way of doing this.

I can use OnCreate...but I believe this is fired really early on i.e. before I know my UserID.

I have been using a kludge by having a button on the form that does the field population and that works fine but any other attempts have led to "undeclared identifier" and "inaccessible from here" error messages. I know this is probably because I don't understand the object model properly but really just looking for a way to get the job done at this point. All help gratefully accepted but as you can tell I am new to all this. Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried e.g. something from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14447331/8041231)?

Comment: "*I can use OnCreate...but I believe this is fired really early on i.e. before I know my UserID*" - only if you are creating the second Form before finishing with the login form. Just don't do that. Create it only after the login Form is done and you are then ready to create it.

Comment: Show us what you have tried, even if it doesn't run.

Comment: OnShow or OnCreate should be usable for this, sounds like you have another problem. Why dont you show us some code so we can try to help you

Comment: Folks, many thanks for your suggestions. I will try these. Will also submit code when I can. Some maths to deal with currently.

Comment: Thanks again, got it all working nicely. I am now using the OnShow event which is perfect. I was getting confused about naming fileds and methods as well but have that sorted now, well at least for he time being.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in comments, the `OnShow` respectively the `OnActivate` event is the way to go here.
To ensure that the event gets executed only once, one could either use a boolean flag (ugly) or set the appropriate form event property to `nil` in the event method itself:

```
procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OnActivate := nil;
  [...]
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OnShow := nil;
  [...]
end;
```