# Delphi - Creating a login form with the option to logout, whilst checking an ini file for login information

Tags: delphi, authentication, passwords, access-violation, ini

I have a login form, a main menu form and a settings form. I have read through tutorials on creating a login form on here and on about.com.

My menu form loads as the main form, whilst the other forms need to be created. I would like users to be able to logout of the main form and return to the login form, so I have followed the accepted answer on this question: [Delphi application with login / logout - how to implement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839648/delphi-application-with-login-logout-how-to-implement)

My login form has a procedure named `CheckLogIn`. It reads the users entered information via edit boxes. It then finds the corresponding username within a local .ini file and reads the stored cypher version of the password. It then un-jumbles the stored password and compares it against the users entered password. If successful, the user should be able to login.

This implementation worked when I was not trying to create the login form after the main menu form. Now that I have created the login form at run-time, I am getting an access violation error at the beginning of my `CheckLogin` procedure.

My current code is as follows:

```
{LOGIN SCREEN}

implementation

uses
  ScrMenu;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure LogIn;
begin
  with TfrmScrLogin.Create(nil) do
    try
      if ShowModal = mrOK then
        Application.MainForm.Show
      else
        Application.Terminate;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;


    function CheckLogin(Sender: TObject):boolean;
var
  iFile: TINIFile;
  i, Count, PLength, Pos1, Pos2: integer;
  User, Cypher, TempPass, Password: string;
begin
  User := frmScrLogin.edtUsername.Text;
  Password := frmScrLogin.edtPassword.Text;
  iFile := TIniFile.Create('C:\MHData.ini');
  Cypher := iFile.ReadString('Users', User, '');
  if Cypher = '' then
    ShowMessage('Username not found')
  else
    begin
      Pos1 := Pos('|', Cypher);
      Pos2 := Pos('\', Cypher);
      PLength := StrToInt(Copy(Cypher, Pos1 + 1, Pos2 - Pos1 - 1));
      Cypher := Copy(Cypher, 0, (Pos1-1));
      Cypher := Copy(Cypher, 0, (Length(Cypher)-PLength));
      for i := 0 to PLength-1 do
        begin
          Count := (i+1)*4;
          TempPass := TempPass + Cypher[Count];
        end;
      if Password = TempPass then
      begin
        Showmessage('login successful');
       frmScrLogin.ModalResult := mrOK;
       Login;
      end
      else
        begin
        ShowMessage('Incorrect password');
        frmScrLogin.edtPassword.Clear;
        frmScrLogin.edtPassword.SetFocus;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Apologies for the untidy editing, I'm not that familiar with the format rules. I also appreciate that many other login questions have had answers where people have said .ini files are a bad idea to store passwords locally. However, this program will not require a high level of security. Thanks in advance

Comment: You never assign a form instance to frmScrLogin, so the value is nil ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo Sorry, I've tried reading up on your answer and changing my code, still no luck. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating the problem yourself by doing

```
with TfrmScrLogin.Create(nil) do
```

That will create an instance of TfrmScrLogin, but doesn't assign the result to the frmScrLogin variable you use in CheckLogin.  That variable will therefore be Nil in CheckLogin, which is what cause the AV.

Instead, do

```
frmLogin := TfrmScrLogin.Create(...
```

Btw, it's a shame that the "with" statement lets one get away with

```
with TSomething.Create
```

because it invites errors like yours.

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you're saying and I've altered my code to assign the TForm.Create to a TForm variable. I'm still getting an error in the same place. Would I need to alter my CheckLogin code to use my variable name instead of frmScrLogin.edtbox? Thanks again

Comment: @MartynA I'm still a little stuck, sorry