# Login logout application using database data for login parameters

Tags: delphi

I have googled for the past hour or so to find some simple tutorial on how to create an application that uses database (Access) parameters (username,password) stored in a table for the authentication purposes, and could find none.I need the ability to switch between the login form and the mainform with ease (login-logout). I am just a beginner in programming so can you point me in the right direction or give me an example on how to do this?

I have seen this example (accepted answer) :
[Delphi application with login / logout - how to implement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839648/delphi-application-with-login-logout-how-to-implement)

I tried this (on loginform button click) but cant make it work right:

```
ADOQuery1.Active:=false;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('select User_name,Password,Access_Level from USERS where User_Name='+QuotedStr(edit1.text)+' and password='+QuotedStr(Edit2.Text));
ADOQuery1.Open;
If ADOQuery1.FieldByName('Password').AsString<>''
    then  Button1.Click
else showmessage('wrongpassword');
Button1.ModalResult := mrNone;
```

Right or wrong password—my main form still shows. Am I messing up?

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the basics on this article for you login:

[Password Login](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/password_login.htm)

You will find articles in this site for other needs as accessing the database, try using their search box: [Delphi About](http://delphi.about.com/) you will find articles on how doing basic things with Delphi with project samples. Very good when it is a beginner !