# Expanding the functionality of existing example

Tags: delphi

This is just for learning sake : Using accepted answer in this example [Delphi application with login / logout - how to implement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839648/delphi-application-with-login-logout-how-to-implement),how can you show a specific form (if you have many forms) ?
I have placed a query on that LoginForm (which displays various forms that can be selected and shown).

[image]

How should I change the existing code so I can accomplish this maintaining the same functionality meaning that whatever form I select and click 'open' it will become the mainform and be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main form is the first form created using `Application.CreateForm`. So use an `if` or `case` statement to conditionally switch which form is created that way.

In pseudo-code:

```
if Form1 is main form then
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1)
else if Form2 is main form then
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2)
....
```

There are quite likely slicker ways to do this, but this is the basic principle.

So, you might well make a function to return the class of the main form, using whatever mechanism you have to choose it:

```
function GetMainFormClass: TFormClass;
begin
  Result :=...; // your logic here
end;
```

Then in the .dpr file you write

```
Application.CreateForm(GetMainFormClass, MainForm);
```

---

You seem, to be really struggling with this. I'll try to spell it out in a little more detail. The implementation of `GetMainFormClass` might look like this:

```
function GetMainFormClass: TFormClass;
var
  FormClassName: string;
begin
  FormClassName := ...; // somehow get the name of the form class, e.g. 'TForm1'
  if FormClassName = 'TForm1' then
    Result := TForm1
  else if FormClassName = 'TForm2' then
    Result := TForm2
  else
    raise EUnrecognisedFormClassName.Create(...);
end;
```

Personally, I don't understand why you are presenting a grid control to the user. To me that seems like a very weak user interface with which to make a selection. I would present a radio group. Then you could write code like this:

```
type
  TMainFormType = (mftForm1, mftForm2, mftForm3);

const 
  MainFormClass = array [TMainFormType] of TFormClass = (
    TForm1,
    TForm2,
    TForm3
  );
```

Then you can have a function that returns `TMainFormType`, by way of showing the user a form and presenting a radio group with three buttons. You can convert the radio group's `ItemIndex` into the appropriate `TMainFormType` value.

```
function GetMainFormType: TMainFormType;
begin
  // ... your UI shows now, presenting the radio group
  Result := TMainFormType(RadioGroup.ItemIndex);
end;
```

And then in the .dpr file you write

```
Application.CreateForm(MainFormClass[GetMainFormType], MainForm);
```

---

There are lots of different ways to do this, but you do need to understand the basics of branching code. Either `if` statements, or lookup tables. If you don't understand how these work then, with all due respect, you need to brush up those skills before you proceed.

Comment: Can you show me where to rearrange all that ? In the login procedure?

Comment: I hoped I just did. Do you understand my answer? If not then me doing more will just be writing your program for you without you gaining understanding. We're not here for that. Do you understand what the main form is, and how it is chosen.

Comment: No,honestly I do not understand you.What will be the main form is based on the selection in the grid. So probably I have to write that somewhere, like:  Var MainForm: FDQuery1.FieldByname('form to open').asString; Or no ?

Comment: If your question is about how to use a grid with a database, why are we talking about main forms? Perhaps you could cut out the extraneous stuff and ask a question just about the part you are stuck on.

Comment: I get : [dcc32 Error] Unit2.pas(38): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TFormClass' and 'string'..... I tried this :Result :=DataModule3.FDQuery1.FieldByname('form_to_open').asString; I am stuck on the part where to tell my app that the mainform is going to be the one selected in the grid and to open it ...:)

Comment: That's a type mismatch error. A string is not a meta class. You'll need to decide how to get from one to the other. A set of if statements would be my advice. Can I ask why you use a database and a grid rather than a simple radio group. Your UI looks clunky.

Comment: I have seen a nice possible solution here :http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=665 but I am unsure where to provide the parameters..

Comment: I think you should be able to do this without copying somebody else's code. It's nothing more than an if statement.

Comment: From swiss example,I need help on this : if Paramstr(1) = DataModule3.FDQuery1.FieldByName('form_to_show').AsString then
  SetAsMainForm(Form1); or does this go with quotedstring?

Comment: i tried : if Paramstr(1) = (DataModule3.FDQuery1.FieldByName('form_to_show').asstring = 'Form1') then  SetAsMainForm(Form1); but I get [dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(26): E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'Boolean' Anyone ? :)

Comment: We don't know what `SetAsMainForm` is. I think you need to learn a little more about the basics of Delphi before you can hope to make progress. Without wishing to seem rude, you are facing relatively simple type mismatch errors. Do you fully understand what E2010 means?

Comment: No,sorry...I am just a beginner...:)

Comment: Frankly, you are asking us to teach you the very basics of programming. You are no longer asking about what is contained in the question. You are asking why `string` and `Boolean` are not compatible. Asking what a type mismatch is. To be honest, you need to learn the language first. Can you see what I mean? At the moment, all I can see in the future of this question is me teaching you how to program in comments. That is not going to happen.